# Spaces after io redirection operator?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I've noticed that when writing a shell script, there's a lot of inconsistency in whether people put a space after the I/O redirection operators. For example:

```
foo >bar.txt
```

Will work, but so will this:

```
foo > bar.txt
```

....and even this:

```
foo       >             bar.txt
```

In fact, even [the Linux Documentation Project page](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) is frustratingly inconsistent about it - using `2>&1` (which doesn't actually work in my *Bash* terminal with spaces) in one place and `> filename` in another!

I've always used the former, as the latter feels like 2 different arguments to me, but I was wondering: Is there any difference or reasoning between the two?

Is `>bar.txt` more portable than `> bar.txt` or something? Or should I use 1 syntax in 1 defined situation, and the other in another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The characters `<`, `>`, `&`, and `|` are special to the shell and are recognized with their special meaning in any position when not quoted.
2. The portable redirection operators are `>`, `>>`, `>|`, `>&`, `<`, `<<`, `<<-`, `<>`. A redirection operator may be preceded with a number indicating a file descriptor; in this case there can be no space between the number and the redirection operator; and the number must be separated from the previous word, if any, with one or more spaces. Other than that, unquoted spaces around the redirection operators are optional.

See [*The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), 2018 edition, [*Shell and Utilities*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html), chapter 2, "[Shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)" for details.